How to browse onedrive with gvfs in Kubuntu?
Ubuntu 24.04 has support for browsing Onedrive. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/set-up-onedrive-file-access-in-ubuntu
How to do the same with Dolphin in Kubuntu?
